# twitter bootstrap tab in a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have modal in twitter bootstrap as follows

```
 <div id="YouTubeDialog" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="windowTitleLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="okClicked();">Close</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#VideoListTab" data-toggle="tab">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#VideoPlayerTab" data-toggle="tab">Player</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="VideoListTab">
             <asp:GridView ID="VideoList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="VideoID,VideoURL" OnRowDataBound="VideoList_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-bordered">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Literal ID="VideoTitle" runat="server" />
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="ViewYouTubeLink" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="View"></asp:HyperLink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView> 
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="VideoPlayerTab">
          <iframe id="youtubeiframe" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="okClicked();">OK</a>
            </div>
```

On the first tab i have a list of videos and on the second tab the player.

i want to click on a button the list in the first list and programatically select the second tab.

i have tried to do this by changing the css to active for the second tab, i was wondering if there is better way to do this?

In addition what i need is while the video is playing, if the user clicks on the first tab then the video in the second tab should stop playing.

any ideas how this can be accomplished?

```
c#, asp.net, jQuery and bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically display a tab by [using Javascript](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) to invoke the tab's link.

```
$('a[href="#VideoPlayerTab"]').tab('show');
```

Alternatively, you could give the link an `id`, or reference it any other way that you see fit.

You can listen to tab events (`'show'` and `'shown'`) that will fire whenever a new tab is being displayed (including when you invoke it, as I showed above).

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    var $previous = $(e.relatedTarget); // previous tab

    if ($previous.data("pause")) {
        var $pauseTab = $($previous.attr('href'));

        // pause video either by ID or by finding it in DOM
    }
});
```

`'show'` will fire *before* the newly selected tab is displayed, so the above event would pause the video before actually displaying the other tab. `'shown'` will fire *after* the newly selected tab is displayed.  Responsiveness would suggest that you can probably pull off pausing the video player after showing them the content again.

Note: in my example above, I use a data field named `'pause'`. This would require an additional attribute to the video tab player's link: `data-pause="true"`. Feel free to do it some other way, including just checking the `href` attribute directly.